# REST service request forwarding to other REST service on another server

Tags: java, rest

I want to implement a simple REST service which may forward the request to another service taking same parameters on another server. I will be behaving like proxy service. In short, called REST service needs to change the base url and forward the request to other service on some other server.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but what is your question?

Comment: How can i achieve this behavior using jersey rest api?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved with Response.temporaryRedirect(URI.create(otherServiceURI)).build();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forward a specific API and add data you should focus on a lightweight platform [RESTX](http://restx.io/) or [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/).

If you simply want to forward all traffic, maybe based on regexp match on the URL and/or body, I would suggest you do it with a dedicated app, script, iptables etc.